# Python proxy with authentification (request,pytrends...)

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy, urllib3

Hello I was previously using older packages and in our corporate I was able to reach outside with proxy with Python in a way:

```py
username = "Platform\\PersonalID"

proxies = {
           "http" : "http://username:password@adress:port", 
           "https" : "http://username:password@adress:port",
          }
```

with for example:

```py
requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
```

However, when I try this on new packages I get a problem with the connection to the proxy and get a timeout error from the urllib3:

"Connection to Platform timed out"

I was able to track it to some changes in urllib3 when I was comparing the old and new packages, but can't figure out how to feed the proxy settings to the requests, pytrends and other packeges (in fact to the new urllib3 which the requests and other libraries are build on)

I have tried to search throught web was looking for several ways how to get the proxy working but failed in one way or another.

for example

If I use the proxies without the password and try to pass the password as an auth=("username","password") then I get error 407 authentication required. Even though the password and ID is correct.

Example:

```py
import requests


proxies = {"http":"http://Platform\\userID:password@adress:port",
           "https": "http://Platform\\userID:password@adress:port"
           }

url="https://www.google.com/"
requests.get(url, proxies=proxies).content
```

works with:
urllib3 up to 1.24

doesnt work with:

urllib3 1.25 (Unable to parse the proxyAdress)

urllib3 1.26.13 (TimeoutError, trying to connect to badly parsed proxyAdress is my tip?)

Comment: Looks like problem with your proxy account only. just to make sure please share a reproducible code block with module versions.

Comment: the sript works till urllib3 version 1.24. With version 1.25 it got LocationParseError (Failed to parse the proxy adress), with version 1.26 it got TimeoutError since its probably trying to reach somehow badly parsed proxy adress.